# Using Notepad++ I need a regular expression to find and replace

Tags: notepad++, regex

Today I learned about regular expressions. Today I also learned that I'm terrible at regular expressions!

I've been toying around with them and have an understanding of some features but what I actually need is vastly ahead of my current knowledge.

Working with thousands of lines like this I need to convert the following:

> ```
>         "MeshURL": "http://cloud-3.steamusercontent.com/ugc/1689401550837946539/FEC7DBCEEDA29A385ADE5D797055307ADB992B03/",
>         "DiffuseURL": "http://cloud-3.steamusercontent.com/ugc/1689401550837944885/196661E00A9EF450B9F008C9126DE66B25E4AAA0/",
>         "ColliderURL": "http://cloud-3.steamusercontent.com/ugc/1689401550837946539/FEC7DBCEEDA29A385ADE5D797055307ADB992B03/",
> ```

Into the following:

> ```
>         "MeshURL": "file:///C:\Users\X\Documents\My Games\Tabletop Simulator\Mods\Models\httpcloud3steamusercontentcomugc1689401550837946539FEC7DBCEEDA29A385ADE5D797055307ADB992B03",
>         "DiffuseURL": "file:///C:\Users\X\Documents\My Games\Tabletop Simulator\Mods\Images\httpcloud3steamusercontentcomugc1689401550837944885196661E00A9EF450B9F008C9126DE66B25E4AAA0",
>         "ColliderURL": "file:///C:\Users\X\Documents\My Games\Tabletop Simulator\Mods\Models\httpcloud3steamusercontentcomugc1689401550837946539FEC7DBCEEDA29A385ADE5D797055307ADB992B03",
> ```

For easier parsing, the distinctions are:

- Removing all symbols from the original URL so it's plain text.
- Replacing "http://" with file:///address (address location dependant on first word in line)

I'm not sure how complex this is, but I theorize it may require tackling in multiple steps. Plus I may need to relocate all files into a single folder for simplicity. Any advise is appreciated although a copy-paste solution would make my day!

Thank you for your time.

Edit: So I'm able to search for URL's with http[^"]+ and I'm able to search for symbols with [^a-zA-Z0-9] but I can't figure out how to combine the search criteria.

Edit2: **Found assistance elsewhere and scripted the process. Thankyou for the suggestions. **

Comment: https://regex101.com/ is a good site to bookmark

Comment: This helps, thanks. But I'm still shooting in the dark unfortunately.

Comment: [FAQ Desk: Where to find REGEX documentation?](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/15765/faq-desk-where-to-find-regex-documentation)

Comment: [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)

Comment: [Regular Expressions Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)

Comment: This is not a job for Notepad++. Write a script in your favorite scripting language.

Answer (score -3):

I'd think `sed` would do this in a jiffy. But you're unwilling to learn. I also think the biggest problem is the c:/ part of it, if you got rid of that then everything becomes zen.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: `sed` has nothing to do with Notepad++, and `sed` basically uses the same regex as Notepad++